# Merge by Distance isn't working as it should

Tags: mesh, modifiers, vertices

[image]

I have been going over some models for our group project and noticed there are double vertices, I suspect these came from a boolean cut. As you can see the vertices are on the same mesh, both vertices are indeed selected and I have even dialled up the merge distance to a ridiculous 1m; yet the vertices are not merging. Very confused as to why this is and would appreciate an explanation and solution, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that they are on a single mesh? - In the Statistics on the top-left of the 3D view you appear to be editing two selected objects out of 82 so you may be trying to merge one vertex from each object. Go back into Object view and see if you have two objects selected.

Comment: Yes it was actually the fact the cupboard and the boolean for the microwave were overlapping! Thank you! I will make a note to keep an eye on the outliner and take a longer look at my stats next time I run into this

Comment: Lucky guess! It was only when I glanced at the stats that I realised what might be happening.